# Formula for matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, binomial-theorem

Consider a sequence of matrices $A_1,\cdots, A_n$. Is there a nice way in which you could write
$$(I-A_1)(I-A_2)\cdots (I-A_n)$$
in terms of some summation? For the first few terms we would get
$$(I-A_1-A_2+A_1A_2)(I-A_3)\cdots (I-A_n)=(I-A_1-A_2+A_1A_2-A_3+A_1A_3+A_2A_3-A_1A_2A_3)(I-A_4)\cdots(I-A_n)$$
but I can't seem to see any pattern emerging. My guess would be someting like the following.
$$(I-A_1)(I-A_2)\cdots (I-A_n)=I-\sum_{k=1}^nA_k +\sum_{(i,j)\in \pi}(-1)^{n+1} A_iA_j+(-1)^{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^nA_k$$
but I'm not too sure what I would be missing here. I am fairly certain what I have here doesn't work. Here $\pi$ denotes some permutation of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$

Comment: Your notation introduces spurious $A_2A_1$ etc.  I'd just leave it as
$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \sum_{1\leq i_1<\dots<i_k\leq n}A_{i_1}\dots A_{i_k}
$ maybe if you are really short of space use `\mathclap` and `\prod` too.

Comment: The product $(I + A_1)(I + A_2) \ldots (I + A_n)$ is the sum of all products of the form $A_{m_1}A_{m_2}\ldots A_{m_k}$, where $m_1, \ldots, m_k$ is a strictly increasing sequence in $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, including the empty product $I$. Just replace $A_i$ with $-A_i$, and you'll just get alternating signs depending on the sign of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

In the following we use the notation $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^n\left(I-A_k\right)}&=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}\prod_{j\in S}\left(-A_j\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{S\subseteq [n]}(-1)^{|S|}\prod_{j\in S}A_j\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,=\color{blue}{\sum_{q=0}^n(-1)^q\sum_{{S\subseteq n}\atop{|S|=q}}\prod_{j\in S}A_j}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we select foreach subset $S\subset [n]$ the matrices $A_j,j\in\{S\}$.
- In (2) we factor out $-1$.
- In (3) we rearrange the sum according to increasing $|S|$.